# Elliptic Curve Point Addition and Multiplication in Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++, elliptic-curve

How to use the point addition and multiplication functions in elliptic curve using Crypto++ library?

I've tried the following code where `Basepoint` and `point` are the points on the elliptic curve.

```
const ECP::Point& ECP::Add(&Basepoint, &point);

ECP::Point& result = ECP::Add(Basepoint, point);

const int result = ECP::Point ECP::Add(&Basepoint, &point);
```

It results in:

> ERROR: E0245 a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a
>   specific object

Comment: You should show more than member function declarations. You should show your code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56273796/608639 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

> ECP::Point& result = ECP::Add(Basepoint, point);

you call `ECP::Add` as a static member of ECP, the error indicates there is no static *Add* , you need to apply it to an instance of ECP

When I look at the [documentation](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_e_c_p.html) I only see

> const Point & Add (const Point &P, const Point &Q) const

which is not static

Also

> const ECP::Point& ECP::Add(&Basepoint, &point);
>
> const int result = ECP::Point ECP::Add(&Basepoint, &point);

are an invalid forms.

Even having just `ECP::Add(&Basepoint, &point);` is also wrong because the operation is not static and because the arguments are pointers to *Point* incompatible with the operation parameters. Probably you have to look at what a reference is in C++ documentation/tutorial

A valid code can be

```
ECP ecp;
Point basepoint;
Point point;

// set ecp, basepoint and point to be the ones you want

const Point & r1 = ecp.Add(basepoint, point); // do not copy the result
Point r2 = ecp.Add(basepoint, point); // copy result in non const to be able to modify it later etc
```

Comment: I've made the object as follows: ECP z1;
ECPPoint result;
result= z1.Add(Basepoint,Basepoint); but it is throwing an exception now: Exception thrown: read access violation.
**CryptoPP::ECP::GetField**(...) returned nullptr. occurred

Comment: @SecurityGeek I do not know ECP, perhaps a default constructed ECP cannot be used for that. I can just react on your initial question to allow you to have a code you can compile ;-)